# Вернуть callback в js

Tags: javascript, ооп, веб-программирование, callback

Не могу вернуть callback, пишет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
var func = {

  CurrentTimeRound : 0,
  MoveTimer : function(sec, finish){

    this.CurrentTimeRound = sec;
    var timer_id = setInterval(function(){

      func.CurrentTimeRound--;

      if(func.CurrentTimeRound > 0){

        $('.rullet-time').removeClass("finish").children('span').text(func.CurrentTimeRound);

      }else{

        clearInterval(timer_id);
        $('.rullet-time').addClass('finish');
        finish();

      }

    }, 1000);

  }

};
```

А так же на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ndthLv7n/)

Вызывается `func.MoveTimer()` в другом файле, первое условие `if` выполняется, так же как и второе, но не вызывает функцию `finish` как `callback`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Спасибо

Comment: где вызывается _MoveTimer_?

Comment: @Grundy, вызывается func.MoveTimer() в другом файле, первое условие if выполняется, так же как и второе, но не вызывает функцию finish как callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове функции `func.MoveTimer` ей либо не передаются параметры, любо вторым параметром передается не функция.

Поэтому получается следующая ошибка.

> вызывается func.MoveTimer()

При таком вызове функции не передается **ни один** аргумент, следовательно внутри функции оба аргумента будут иметь значение *undefined*.

Передавайте аргументы в функцию, и все заработает.

Comment: Параметры передаются, не работает только функция finish как callback

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан, дополнил ответ.

Comment: По участвовала моя не внимательность, прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, неправильная передача аргументов в функцию. Вот так работает: передача самой функции:

```
 var func = {

CurrentTimeRound : 0,
MoveTimer : function(sec, finish){

    this.CurrentTimeRound = sec;
    var timer_id = setInterval(function(){

        func.CurrentTimeRound--;

        if(func.CurrentTimeRound > 0){

            //$('.rullet-time').removeClass("finish").children('span').text(func.CurrentTimeRound);

        }else{

            clearInterval(timer_id);
            //$('.rullet-time').addClass('finish');
            finish();

        }

    }, 1000);

}

};

func.MoveTimer(1,function(){console.log("Hi!")})
```